# Which edac module should I enable here?

Tags: linux, kernel, x86

I got a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz` CPU here , not sure which module should be enabled for EDAC:

[image]

Chipset:  `Inter Coporation 6 Series/C2000` , driver in use: `i801_smbus`

Comment: One option to find out is to compile them all as modules, then boot the machine and see which one gets loaded. I used to try and figure out which exact modules where required for booting my system, but it turned out to just be a lot of work and with the smallest changes in set up I had to figure out the kernel configuration all over again. When disk space is not an issue, I'd compile the default set of modules or all (/most).

Comment: It depends on your motherboard chipset more than your CPU.

Comment: @cjm, not anymore.  Memory controller on all Nehalem and newer is built into the CPU, not the North Bridge.  So as long as the motherboard supports it (need more wires from memory to CPU since ECC uses 9 bits to store 8 bits with the extra redundancy), plugging in different CPU's can give you the ECC capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is `Sandy Bridge`, after digging a bit in Intel's site.